# Sort on underlying data in ng-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, ng-grid

I wish to display a formatted value in a ng-grid cell, but sort on a related numeric value not displayed.

```
var myData1 = [{
 name: "Moroni",
  age: 50,
  ageWord: "Fifty"
}
```

From the above example I would display the ageWord column, but wish to sort on the age column.

The [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) for sorting an ng-grid directive indicate I can provide a custom function to sort underlying data:

**sortFn**

> Sets the sort function for the column. Useful when you have data that is formatted in an unusual way or if you want to **sort on an underlying data type**. Check the MDN sort docs for examples

the custom sort function receives the display values when the column sort is clicked, but I wish to sort on the age.  If I had the row available in the sort function I could sort on the sibling cell, something like this:

```
sortFn: function(a, b) {
    var ageA = a.getProperty('age');
    var ageB = b.getProperty('age');
    return ageA-ageB;
  }
```

Any suggestions how I can sort by 'age' when the 'ageWord' column is sorted?  Example available [on plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4PRYP53z99JIwD1s2dU9?p=preview).

Comment: you could use  `field:'age', cellFilter: 'toWord'` and write a filter toWord(num)? Similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766951/convert-digits-into-words-with-javascript

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to define your column as an object and define your **cellTemplate**. Then use the age property in your sortFn (http://plnkr.co/edit/qmBsneZ3HmFRKSkjbBWU?p=preview):

```
// main.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    //Notice age is now an object to be used with the cellTemplate
    var myData1 = [{name: "Moroni", age: {age: 50, ageWord: "Fifty"}},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: {age: 43, ageWord: "Forty-Three"}},
                     {name: "Mildred", age: {age: 70, ageWord: "Seventy"}},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: {age: 27, ageWord: "Twenty-Seven"}}];


    $scope.gridOptions = { 
      data: 'gridData',
       columnDefs: [
        {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'}, 
        {field:'age', 
         displayName:'Age',
         cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text>{{COL_FIELD.ageWord}}</span></div>',
         sortFn: function (a, b) {
           //compare age property of the object
           if (a.age < b.age) {
             return -1;
           }
           else if (a.age > b.age) {
             return 1;
           }
           else {
             return 0;
           }
         }
       }]
    };

    $scope.gridData = myData1;

});
```

According to the docs, cellTemplate defaults to:

```
<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text>{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</span></div>
```

So all you need to do is use {{COL_FIELD.age}} and any custom filters you may (or may not) have.

Comment: Worked brilliantly and a game changer for how I was previously preparing/displaying my data. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You could use `sortInfo` in your `gridOptions`, like this:

```
 $scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'gridData',
    columnDefs: [
      {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'}, 
      {field:'ageWord', displayName: 'Age'}
    ],
    sortInfo: {
      fields: ['age'],
      directions: ['asc']
    }
};
```

Comment: sortInfo provides the "initial" sort upon first view.  "Define a sortInfo object to specify a default sorting state. "  It does not affect the column sort click event.