# Sort on underlying data in ng-grid_

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the same question with the below poster about sortFn in ng-grid:
[Sort on underlying data in ng-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706684/sort-on-underlying-data-in-ng-grid)
the answer give the code in Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/qmBsneZ3HmFRKSkjbBWU?p=preview

```
 var myData1 = [{name: "Moroni", age: {age: 50, ageWord: "Fifty"}},
                 {name: "Tiancum", age: {age: 43, ageWord: "Forty-Three"}},
                 {name: "Mildred", age: {age: 70, ageWord: "Seventy"}},
                 {name: "Jacob", age: {age: 27, ageWord: "Twenty-Seven"}}];

 $scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'gridData',
   columnDefs: [
    {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'}, 
    {field:'age', 
     displayName:'Age',
     cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text>{{COL_FIELD.ageWord}}</span></div>',
     sortFn: function (a, b) {
       if (a.age < b.age) {
         return -1;
       }
       else if (a.age > b.age) {
         return 1;
       }
       else {
         return 0;
       }
     }
       }]
};
```

But, it did not change the list queue, in my opinion, the list would be 'Twenty-Seven,Forty-Three,Fifty,Seventy' correct?
If not, how can i sort the ngGrid by sortFn keyword? All, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at this fork: [I've modified it to have the age column as the default sort field and set the direction to ascending](http://plnkr.co/edit/MJweQzNuVbmRevktJbbz?p=preview).

This needs to be set as an option in order for this to take effect:

```
sortInfo: { fields: ['age'], directions: ['asc'] }
```

Comment: thanks, I already known sortInfo work well in ngGrid, but here the sort Key is an object, and i do not think it fit up;

Comment: A object key sort will work just the same as a direct value sort :)