# Angular directive/service to convert number into words (need in Angularjs)?

Tags: angularjs

I want to convert number into words. Like 234 in word would be 2 hundred thirty-four. Similarly 1000 will be  one thousand. Similarly 100 means one hundred.

Is there any library for this in angularjs. If then how we will write in angularjs directive/service so that we can use it again..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766951/convert-digits-into-words-with-javascript

Answer (score 17):

Create a words filter.

[image]

I got the "toWords" algorithm from this blog post: http://ravindersinghdang.blogspot.com/2013/04/convert-numbers-into-words-using.html

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.filter('words', function() {
  function isInteger(x) {
        return x % 1 === 0;
    }

  
  return function(value) {
    if (value && isInteger(value))
      return  toWords(value);
    
    return value;
  };

});


var th = ['','thousand','million', 'billion','trillion'];
var dg = ['zero','one','two','three','four', 'five','six','seven','eight','nine']; 
var tn = ['ten','eleven','twelve','thirteen', 'fourteen','fifteen','sixteen', 'seventeen','eighteen','nineteen'];
var tw = ['twenty','thirty','forty','fifty', 'sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety']; 


function toWords(s)
{  
    s = s.toString(); 
    s = s.replace(/[\, ]/g,''); 
    if (s != parseFloat(s)) return 'not a number'; 
    var x = s.indexOf('.'); 
    if (x == -1) x = s.length; 
    if (x > 15) return 'too big'; 
    var n = s.split(''); 
    var str = ''; 
    var sk = 0; 
    for (var i=0; i < x; i++) 
    {
        if ((x-i)%3==2) 
        {
            if (n[i] == '1') 
            {
                str += tn[Number(n[i+1])] + ' '; 
                i++; 
                sk=1;
            }
            else if (n[i]!=0) 
            {
                str += tw[n[i]-2] + ' ';
                sk=1;
            }
        }
        else if (n[i]!=0) 
        {
            str += dg[n[i]] +' '; 
            if ((x-i)%3==0) str += 'hundred ';
            sk=1;
        }


        if ((x-i)%3==1)
        {
            if (sk) str += th[(x-i-1)/3] + ' ';
            sk=0;
        }
    }
    if (x != s.length)
    {
        var y = s.length; 
        str += 'point '; 
        for (var i=x+1; i<y; i++) str += dg[n[i]] +' ';
    }
    return str.replace(/\s+/g,' ');
}

window.toWords = toWords;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  
  <input type="text" ng-model="name" /> {{name | words}}
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason why you did the `window.toWords = toWords;` instead of just including the function `toWords()` and variables within the filter?

Comment: Thanks for the resource, very helpful

Comment: is it possible with angular2?

Answer (score 0):

I have done [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63099148/7355075) for Angular 8.
It also works for float/double numbers.