# convert numerical value(amount) into text angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, numbers

I am creating a web based application in mvc-5 using angularJS i am getting a sum of amount in my table

```
<td><span style="font-weight:bolder; font-size:24px; float:right;">Total: {{totalAmount}}</span></td>
```

I am getting the amount from the controller like this

```
$scope.totalAmount = 0;
$scope.tableindiv2.forEach(function (t) {
   $scope.totalAmount += Number(t.amount);
   $scope.empnameandaddress();
});
```

Here i want to convert the amount from numbers to text. For example, if the total is `4526`, it should show `four thousand five hundred twenty six`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert from number to words like done in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14767071/5084000) answer.

```
var a = ['','one ','two ','three ','four ', 'five ','six ','seven ','eight ','nine ','ten ','eleven ','twelve ','thirteen ','fourteen ','fifteen ','sixteen ','seventeen ','eighteen ','nineteen '];
var b = ['', '', 'twenty','thirty','forty','fifty', 'sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety'];

function inWords (num) {
    if ((num = num.toString()).length > 9) return 'overflow';
    n = ('000000000' + num).substr(-9).match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{2})$/);
    if (!n) return; var str = '';
    str += (n[1] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[1])] || b[n[1][0]] + ' ' + a[n[1][1]]) + 'crore ' : '';
    str += (n[2] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[2])] || b[n[2][0]] + ' ' + a[n[2][1]]) + 'lakh ' : '';
    str += (n[3] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[3])] || b[n[3][0]] + ' ' + a[n[3][1]]) + 'thousand ' : '';
    str += (n[4] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[4])] || b[n[4][0]] + ' ' + a[n[4][1]]) + 'hundred ' : '';
    str += (n[5] != 0) ? ((str != '') ? 'and ' : '') + (a[Number(n[5])] || b[n[5][0]] + ' ' + a[n[5][1]]) + 'only ' : '';
    return str;
}

$scope.totalAmount = 0;
$scope.tableindiv2.forEach(function (t) {
   $scope.totalAmount += Number(t.amount);
   $scope.empnameandaddress();
});

$scope.totalAmountInWords = inWords($scope.totalAmount);
```

In your HTML view, use `totalAmountInWords` instead of `totalAmount`.

```
style="font-weight:bolder; font-size:24px; float:right;">Total: {{totalAmountInWords }}</span></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create word filter which convert number to text

Please refer this [Angular directive/service to convert number into words (need in Angularjs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649013/angular-directive-service-to-convert-number-into-words-need-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

I have done [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63099148/7355075) for Angular 8.
It can also convert float/double numbers into word.