# convert amount in words in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to convert amount in words. For example, the amount I will get it from service is 9876, I need to display in a table "Nine Thousand Eight Hundred and Seventy Six" in a table.

I need to do this using angularjs. Please help me how can I do this.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/5tt7d3e6/)

```js
function convertNumberToWords(amount) {
    var words = new Array();
    words[0] = '';
    words[1] = 'One';
    words[2] = 'Two';
    words[3] = 'Three';
    words[4] = 'Four';
    words[5] = 'Five';
    words[6] = 'Six';
    words[7] = 'Seven';
    words[8] = 'Eight';
    words[9] = 'Nine';
    words[10] = 'Ten';
    words[11] = 'Eleven';
    words[12] = 'Twelve';
    words[13] = 'Thirteen';
    words[14] = 'Fourteen';
    words[15] = 'Fifteen';
    words[16] = 'Sixteen';
    words[17] = 'Seventeen';
    words[18] = 'Eighteen';
    words[19] = 'Nineteen';
    words[20] = 'Twenty';
    words[30] = 'Thirty';
    words[40] = 'Forty';
    words[50] = 'Fifty';
    words[60] = 'Sixty';
    words[70] = 'Seventy';
    words[80] = 'Eighty';
    words[90] = 'Ninety';
    amount = amount.toString();
    var atemp = amount.split(".");
    var number = atemp[0].split(",").join("");
    var n_length = number.length;
    var words_string = "";
    if (n_length <= 9) {
        var n_array = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        var received_n_array = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < n_length; i++) {
            received_n_array[i] = number.substr(i, 1);
        }
        for (var i = 9 - n_length, j = 0; i < 9; i++, j++) {
            n_array[i] = received_n_array[j];
        }
        for (var i = 0, j = 1; i < 9; i++, j++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 7) {
                if (n_array[i] == 1) {
                    n_array[j] = 10 + parseInt(n_array[j]);
                    n_array[i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        value = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 7) {
                value = n_array[i] * 10;
            } else {
                value = n_array[i];
            }
            if (value != 0) {
                words_string += words[value] + " ";
            }
            if ((i == 1 && value != 0) || (i == 0 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
                words_string += "Crores ";
            }
            if ((i == 3 && value != 0) || (i == 2 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
                words_string += "Lakhs ";
            }
            if ((i == 5 && value != 0) || (i == 4 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
                words_string += "Thousand ";
            }
            if (i == 6 && value != 0 && (n_array[i + 1] != 0 && n_array[i + 2] != 0)) {
                words_string += "Hundred and ";
            } else if (i == 6 && value != 0) {
                words_string += "Hundred ";
            }
        }
        words_string = words_string.split("  ").join(" ");
    }
    return words_string;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Number OR Amount" onkeyup="word.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(this.value)" />
<div id="word"></div>
```

I refered this javascript fiddle. But I want to it in a angularjs.

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: Need to show Amount(Numbers) in words using angularjs.

Comment: it is not a question, it is requirement, what is your question?

Comment: I suggest you to define a filter and use this filter in every where you want.

Comment: @hadi.mansouri I'm new in angularjs. Can you pls send any sample code.

Comment: @sathishkumar As llya Bursov told your question is not so clear (It is requirement. What is your question exactly?). Anyway I suggest you an easy possible way to use your mentioned sample function in angularjs. Follow my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used this for Angular 8.
**Input** : 123456789.09   **Output** : twelve crore thirty four lakh fifty six thousand seven eighty nine point zero nine

```
n: string;
a = ['zero ', 'one ', 'two ', 'three ', 'four ', 'five ', 'six ', 'seven ', 'eight ', 'nine ', 'ten ', 'eleven ', 'twelve ', 'thirteen ', 'fourteen ', 'fifteen ', 'sixteen ', 'seventeen ', 'eighteen ', 'nineteen '];
b = ['', '', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];
 
 ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.inWords(123456789.09));
 }

inWords (num): string {
    num = Math.floor(num * 100);
    if ((num = num.toString()).length > 11) { return 'overflow'; }
   let n;
   n = ('00000000' + num).substr(-11).match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{1})$/);
        if (!n) { return; } let str = ''; 

     // tslint:disable-next-line:triple-equals
     str += (n[1] != 0) ? (this.a[Number(n[1])] || this.b[n[1][0]] + ' ' + this.a[n[1][1]]) + 'crore ' : '';
     // tslint:disable-next-line:triple-equals
        str += (n[2] != 0) ? (this.a[Number(n[2])] || this.b[n[2][0]] + ' ' + this.a[n[2][1]]) + 'lakh ' : '';
     // tslint:disable-next-line:triple-equals
     str += (n[3] != 0) ? (this.a[Number(n[3])] || this.b[n[3][0]] + ' ' + this.a[n[3][1]]) + 'thousand ' : '';
     // tslint:disable-next-line:triple-equals
     str += (n[4] != 0) ? (this.a[Number(n[4])] || this.b[n[4][0]] + ' ' + this.a[n[4][1]]) : 'hundred';
     // tslint:disable-next-line:triple-equals
     str += (n[5]) ? (this.a[Number(n[5])] || this.b[n[5][0]] + ' ' + this.a[n[5][1]]) : '';
     // tslint:disable-next-line:triple-equals
     str += (n[6]) ?  ((str != '') ? 'point ' : '') + (this.a[Number(n[6])] || this.b[n[6][0]] + ' ' + this.a[n[6][1]]) : '';
     // tslint:disable-next-line:triple-equals
     str += (n[7] != 0) ? (this.a[Number(n[7])] || this.b[n[7][0]] + ' ' + this.a[n[7][1]]) : '';

     return str;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Define a filter to convert number to word such as following code:

```
angular.module('myModuleName')

.filter('convertToWord', function() {
    return function(amount) {
        var words = new Array();
        words[0] = '';
        words[1] = 'One';
        words[2] = 'Two';
        words[3] = 'Three';
        words[4] = 'Four';
        words[5] = 'Five';
        words[6] = 'Six';
        words[7] = 'Seven';
        words[8] = 'Eight';
        words[9] = 'Nine';
        words[10] = 'Ten';
        words[11] = 'Eleven';
        words[12] = 'Twelve';
        words[13] = 'Thirteen';
        words[14] = 'Fourteen';
        words[15] = 'Fifteen';
        words[16] = 'Sixteen';
        words[17] = 'Seventeen';
        words[18] = 'Eighteen';
        words[19] = 'Nineteen';
        words[20] = 'Twenty';
        words[30] = 'Thirty';
        words[40] = 'Forty';
        words[50] = 'Fifty';
        words[60] = 'Sixty';
        words[70] = 'Seventy';
        words[80] = 'Eighty';
        words[90] = 'Ninety';
        amount = amount.toString();
        var atemp = amount.split(".");
        var number = atemp[0].split(",").join("");
        var n_length = number.length;
        var words_string = "";
        if (n_length <= 9) {
            var n_array = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            var received_n_array = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < n_length; i++) {
                received_n_array[i] = number.substr(i, 1);
            }
            for (var i = 9 - n_length, j = 0; i < 9; i++, j++) {
                n_array[i] = received_n_array[j];
            }
            for (var i = 0, j = 1; i < 9; i++, j++) {
                if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 7) {
                    if (n_array[i] == 1) {
                        n_array[j] = 10 + parseInt(n_array[j]);
                        n_array[i] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            value = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 7) {
                    value = n_array[i] * 10;
                } else {
                    value = n_array[i];
                }
                if (value != 0) {
                    words_string += words[value] + " ";
                }
                if ((i == 1 && value != 0) || (i == 0 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
                    words_string += "Crores ";
                }
                if ((i == 3 && value != 0) || (i == 2 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
                    words_string += "Lakhs ";
                }
                if ((i == 5 && value != 0) || (i == 4 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
                    words_string += "Thousand ";
                }
                if (i == 6 && value != 0 && (n_array[i + 1] != 0 && n_array[i + 2] != 0)) {
                    words_string += "Hundred and ";
                } else if (i == 6 && value != 0) {
                    words_string += "Hundred ";
                }
            }
            words_string = words_string.split("  ").join(" ");
        }
        return words_string;
    };
});
```

Then in your templates (views) use this filter as follow:

```
{{amount | converToWord}}
```

For example to show inserted value in an input field:

```
<input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Number OR Amount" ng-model="myValue" />
<div id="word">{{myValue | convertToWord}}</div>
```