# Simplest way to return get the word value for a key in an ng repeat? e.g. 1 = One?

Tags: angularjs

I am outputting a list in angular from an object.

The object can contain anywhere from 0 - 100 items and the design I have to work to use the word for the numbers as the list item name.

E.g. currently:

```
<li ng-repeat="result in results">
    {{ $index }}
</li>
```

Will return 0,1,2,3 etc. But I need to instead show one, two, three...

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Check out this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766951/convert-digits-into-words-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do `{{$index +1}}`.

Then apply a custom filter to the this number. 
See [Angular directive/service to convert number into words (need in Angularjs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649013/angular-directive-service-to-convert-number-into-words-need-in-angularjs) for creating a custom filter that converts a number to a word.

Comment: I need the word value, so One two three, not 1 2 3.

Comment: My mistake, you'd have to write a custom filter to display it as a word. Unfortunately there are no built-in AngularJS filters for doing that. I'm sure you could easily find an example online of a custom filter that translates a number into its respective word(s).