# currency conversion:number to words excel

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets

I would like to convert the the Kuwait currency which has  three decimal places into words in an Excel Document.The formula i used is as follows:

```
=if(or(isBlank($E$89),not(isNumber($E$89)),$E$89>=power(10,15)),ifError(1/0),trim(arrayFormula(concatenate(if(trunc(mod($E$89,power(10,15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,{12,9,6,3,0}))<100,"",switch(int(trunc(mod($E$89,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,{12,9,6,3,0}))/100),1," one",2," two",3," three",4," four",5," five",6," six",7," seven",8," eight",9," nine") & " hundred") & if(mod(trunc(mod($E$89,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,{12,9,6,3,0})),100)<>0,if(trunc(mod($E$89,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,{12,9,6,3,0}))>100," and",if($E$89>power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}),switch({1,2,3,4,5},5," and"),"")),"") & if(mod(trunc(mod($E$89,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,12,9,6,3,0})),100)=0,"",if(mod(trunc(mod($E$89,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,{12,9,6,3,0})),100)<20,IFERROR(switch(mod(trunc(mod($E$89,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,{12,9,6,3,0})),100),1," one",2," two",3," three",4," four",5," five",6," six",7," seven",8," eight",9," nine",10," ten",11," eleven",12," twelve",13," thirteen",14," fourteen",15," fifteen",16," sixteen",17," seventeen",18," eighteen",19," nineteen")),IFERROR(switch(int(mod(trunc(mod($E$89,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,{12,9,6,3,0})),100)/10),2," twenty",3," thirty",4," forty",5," fifty",6," sixty",7," seventy",8," eighty",9," ninety")) & if(mod(mod(trunc(mod($E$89,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,12,9,6,3,0})),100),10)=0,"","-" & IFERROR(switch(mod(mod(trunc(mod($E$89,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,{12,9,6,3,0})),100),10),1,"one",2,"two",3,"three",4,"four",5,"five",6,"six",7,"seven",8,"eight",9,"nine"))))) & if(trunc(mod($E$89,power(10,{15,12,9,6,3}))/power(10,{12,9,6,3,0}))=0,"",IFERROR(switch({1,2,3,4,5},1," trillion",2," billion",3," million",4," thousand"))))) & if($E$89>=2," Dinar only",if($E$89>=1," Dinar only","")) & if((round($E$89-trunc($E$89),3)*1000=0)+($E$89<1),""," and") & switch(trunc(round($E$89-trunc($E$89),3)*1000,-2)/100,1," one-hundred",2," two",3,-hundred" three-hundred",4," four-hundred",5," five-hundred",6," six-hundred",7," seven-hundred",8," eight-hundred",9," nine-hundred"& if(round($E$89-trunc($E$89),3)*1000-trunc(round($E$89-trunc($E$89),3)*1000,-2)<20,switch(round($E$89-trunc($E$89),3)*1000-trunc(round($E$89-trunc($E$89),3)*1000,-1),0,"",1," one",2," two",3," three",4," four",5," five",6," six",7," seven",8," eight",9," nine",10," ten",11," eleven",12," twelve",13," thirteen",14," fourteen",15," fifteen",16," sixteen",17," seventeen",18," eighteen",19," nineteen"),switch((round($E$89-trunc($E$89),3)*1000-trunc(round($E$89-trunc($E$89),3)*1000,-2))/10,2," twenty",3," thirty",4," forty",5," fifty",6," sixty",7," seventy",8," eighty",9," ninety") & if(mod(round($E$89-trunc($E$89),3)*1000,10)=0,"","-" & switch(round($E$89-trunc($E$89),3)*1000-trunc(round($E$89-trunc($E$89),3)*1000,-1),0"",1,"one",2,"two",3,"three",4,"four",5,"five",6,"six",7,"seven",8,"eight",9,"nine"))) & " fils only")))
```

The error shown is

> Formula parse error

For a given input:

> 111.250

i would expect to get the output as :

> One hundred and eleven Dinar and two hundred fifty fils only.

Comment: That formula is longer than any formula should ever be. What you should really be asking is *how can I get `x` to look like `y`* - because I'm sure people here will be able to come up with a much better solution than fixing your parse error. But you absolutely did the right thing by showing us what you have tried... it shows effort on your part, which will encourage plenty of people to help.

Comment: Sorry - what I meant to say a bit more clearly was this: please edit your question to include some sample data and what you expect the output to look like

Comment: Thanks for the correction.Updated the question.

Comment: See [How to convert a numeric value into English words in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213360/how-to-convert-a-numeric-value-into-english-words-in-excel). You should have no problem converting any regional differences for your own purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if i write the code in a visual basic editor the function is only available to my system right? I wanted a global function that can be used to get the expected output from any system.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for JavaScript solutions to use then as [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).

I've found is this code, provided by @Vilas Shetkar:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37409158/5372400

I've tested this code and it works in sheets, so you may adopt this or other similar solutions to your needs.