# How insert JavaScript into Vue file

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I found a `number to words` script, and want to use this script in a `.vue` file, but can't find where to insert this script. Maybe someone can help where to insert this script? and how to change `onkeyup` which works on vuejs2

```js
function convertNumberToWords(amount) {
    var words = new Array();
    words[0] = '';
    words[1] = 'One';
    words[2] = 'Two';
    words[3] = 'Three';
    words[4] = 'Four';
    words[5] = 'Five';
    words[6] = 'Six';
    words[7] = 'Seven';
    words[8] = 'Eight';
    words[9] = 'Nine';
    words[10] = 'Ten';
    words[11] = 'Eleven';
    words[12] = 'Twelve';
    words[13] = 'Thirteen';
    words[14] = 'Fourteen';
    words[15] = 'Fifteen';
    words[16] = 'Sixteen';
    words[17] = 'Seventeen';
    words[18] = 'Eighteen';
    words[19] = 'Nineteen';
    words[20] = 'Twenty';
    words[30] = 'Thirty';
    words[40] = 'Forty';
    words[50] = 'Fifty';
    words[60] = 'Sixty';
    words[70] = 'Seventy';
    words[80] = 'Eighty';
    words[90] = 'Ninety';
    amount = amount.toString();
    var atemp = amount.split(".");
    var number = atemp[0].split(",").join("");
    var n_length = number.length;
    var words_string = "";
    if (n_length <= 9) {
        var n_array = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        var received_n_array = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < n_length; i++) {
            received_n_array[i] = number.substr(i, 1);
        }
        for (var i = 9 - n_length, j = 0; i < 9; i++, j++) {
            n_array[i] = received_n_array[j];
        }
        for (var i = 0, j = 1; i < 9; i++, j++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 7) {
                if (n_array[i] == 1) {
                    n_array[j] = 10 + parseInt(n_array[j]);
                    n_array[i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        value = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 7) {
                value = n_array[i] * 10;
            } else {
                value = n_array[i];
            }
            if (value != 0) {
                words_string += words[value] + " ";
            }
            if ((i == 1 && value != 0) || (i == 0 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
                words_string += "Crores ";
            }
            if ((i == 3 && value != 0) || (i == 2 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
                words_string += "Hundred and ";
            }
            if ((i == 5 && value != 0) || (i == 4 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
                words_string += "Thousand ";
            }
            if (i == 6 && value != 0 && (n_array[i + 1] != 0 && n_array[i + 2] != 0)) {
                words_string += "Hundred and ";
            } else if (i == 6 && value != 0) {
                words_string += "Hundred ";
            }
        }
        words_string = words_string.split("  ").join(" ");
    }
    return words_string;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Number OR Amount" onkeyup="word.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(this.value)" />
<div id="word"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really not taking advantage of Vue doing it that way.  You don't need to use manual event handlers or direct DOM manipulation at all at all; instead let the framework take care of it for you.  One way is to use a computed property based on the input value:

#### Computed Property:

```
<input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Number OR Amount" v-model="theNumber">
<div id="word" v-html="theWord"></div>

...

computed: {
   theWord() {
      // your "convertNumberToWords" function here, using `this.theNumber` as its input, and returning the word you want displayed in the DOM
      return "foo"; 
   }
}
```

Whenever the v-model `theNumber` changes, the computed `theWord` function will automatically run and update the DOM.

Below is a functioning example containing your complete "number to words" function:

```js
Vue.component('theComponent', {
  template: `
    <span>
      <input v-model="theNumber">
      <div v-html="theWord"></div>
    </span>`,
  data() {
    return {
      theNumber: '1'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    theWord() { 
      var words = new Array();
      words[0] = '';
      words[1] = 'One';
      words[2] = 'Two';
      words[3] = 'Three';
      words[4] = 'Four';
      words[5] = 'Five';
      words[6] = 'Six';
      words[7] = 'Seven';
      words[8] = 'Eight';
      words[9] = 'Nine';
      words[10] = 'Ten';
      words[11] = 'Eleven';
      words[12] = 'Twelve';
      words[13] = 'Thirteen';
      words[14] = 'Fourteen';
      words[15] = 'Fifteen';
      words[16] = 'Sixteen';
      words[17] = 'Seventeen';
      words[18] = 'Eighteen';
      words[19] = 'Nineteen';
      words[20] = 'Twenty';
      words[30] = 'Thirty';
      words[40] = 'Forty';
      words[50] = 'Fifty';
      words[60] = 'Sixty';
      words[70] = 'Seventy';
      words[80] = 'Eighty';
      words[90] = 'Ninety';
      amount = this.theNumber.toString();
      var atemp = amount.split(".");
      var number = atemp[0].split(",").join("");
      var n_length = number.length;
      var words_string = "";
      if (n_length <= 9) {
        var n_array = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        var received_n_array = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < n_length; i++) {
          received_n_array[i] = number.substr(i, 1);
        }
        for (var i = 9 - n_length, j = 0; i < 9; i++, j++) {
          n_array[i] = received_n_array[j];
        }
        for (var i = 0, j = 1; i < 9; i++, j++) {
          if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 7) {
            if (n_array[i] == 1) {
              n_array[j] = 10 + parseInt(n_array[j]);
              n_array[i] = 0;
            }
          }
        }
        value = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
          if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 7) {
            value = n_array[i] * 10;
          } else {
            value = n_array[i];
          }
          if (value != 0) {
            words_string += words[value] + " ";
          }
          if ((i == 1 && value != 0) || (i == 0 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
            words_string += "Crores ";
          }
          if ((i == 3 && value != 0) || (i == 2 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
            words_string += "Hundred and ";
          }
          if ((i == 5 && value != 0) || (i == 4 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
            words_string += "Thousand ";
          }
          if (i == 6 && value != 0 && (n_array[i + 1] != 0 && n_array[i + 2] != 0)) {
            words_string += "Hundred and ";
          } else if (i == 6 && value != 0) {
            words_string += "Hundred ";
          }
        }
        words_string = words_string.split("  ").join(" ");
      }
      return words_string;

    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <the-component></the-component>
</div>
```

#### Filter:

Alternatively, if you're using this same function frequently throughout your app, it might be better to implement it as a [filter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html) instead. Define the filter in your main.js and it will be available in all components:

```
Vue.filter('numberToWord', function (value) {
  // your function here
})

<!-- these are equivalent: -->
<span>{{theNumber | numberToWord}}</span>
<span>{{filters.numberToWord(theNumber)}}</span>
```

#### Converting numbers to words:

Incidentally: this isn't directly relevant to your question but there are some issues with the number-to-words function itself you should be aware of; it fails for many input values above 99,999 -- 100001 comes out as "One Hundred And One" for example -- and uses the regionally-specific term "Crores" for ten million, which you may want to remove unless your site is for an audience that will be familiar with that term.

[Here are several other implementations of the same idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766951/convert-digits-into-words-with-javascript), some of which may be preferable to the one used above.

Comment: Thanks, you very much now its more clear to me, but when i try to do with first example i get this error "[Vue warn]: Error in render: "ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable amount""

Comment: Looks like the function wasn't written for strict mode: it includes a few undeclared variables; you'd need to go through it and update those lines to satisfy the linter (`var amount = this.theNumber.toString` instead of just `amount = this.etc`)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways to do it.

You can add this script to another Javascript file and import it into your script section in the `.vue` file.

```
<script>
import numberToWords from 'utils';
....   
</script>
```

Or you could create a method in your component with this function inside it.

In my opinion, the first version is better because you can reuse it in all your components.

Answer (score 0):

`.vue` files accept all valid JavaScript code, so you could either simply place this function in your Vue component in the `methods` object and use it normally, or if you would like to use this across many components you can also place it in a file and import it into your component(s).

[How to import JS libraries](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/04/22/vue-js-libraries-plugins/)

Comment: Thanks, and maybe can help with html how to change onkeyup and when what to write into div ?

Comment: You would bind the onkeyup event using v-bind or : as a shortcut :onkeyup="convertNumberToWords()" It is important to note that the event object will be passed automatically to the called function and can be used to retrieve the input value via `convertNumberToWords(event) { event.target.value }` You could also bind the input value to a piece of data and pass that to the function.