# Add a literal number (three) by 1 (four)

Tags: javascript, node.js, numbers, discord, discord.js

```js
var T2W = require("numbers2words");
var translator = new T2W("EN_US");
const { wordsToNumbers } = require('words-to-numbers');
let numbr = wordsToNumbers(message.content.toLowerCase());
message.channel.send(translator.toWords(numbr + 1));
```

So this is in `bot.on('message', async message) =>`. I’ve tried using other Node.js libraries, like [words-to-numbers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/words-to-numbers) and [numbers2words](https://www.npmjs.com/package/numbers2words).

My idea is that, for example, somebody says “three” and the bot responds with “four”, by converting the message’s number (`"three"` to `3`), adding `1` (`4`), and then converting it back to a literal number (`"four"`).

I’d be grateful to anybody that will answer this, I’m clueless! =)

Comment: `bot.on('message', async message) => ` should throw a Syntax Error

Comment: You described what you did, but not what your problem is.

Comment: Your problem cannot be in form: do the thing from scratch for me. Sth more specific. What have you tried, what is the specific error you get. Or where you are stuck?

Comment: I'm stuck. The bot won't answer at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Easier/Simpler method

**You can use these two libraries to convert numbers into words vice-versa:**

words-to-numbers: https://www.npmjs.com/package/words-to-numbers

numbers-to-words: https://www.npmjs.com/package/number-to-words

*The links contain more information on how to use the libraries.*

---

### Harder/Longer method

You can make your own function that takes in a number or a worded number and then returns both the number and the worded number. For that, you can *(as far as I know)* create a couple arrays e.g. `["one", "two", "three"]`, `["hundred", thousand", "million"]` and use RegEx.

I found a similar-asked-post on StackOverflow where you can view the code on how to code your own: [Convert digits into words with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766951/convert-digits-into-words-with-javascript).

---

By the way, you will get a syntax error because you forgot a parentheses.

You wrote:
`bot.on("message", async message) => {});`

Should be:
`bot.on("message", async (message) => {});` or `bot.on("message, async message => {});`

---

Comment: I was just specifying that I’ve put it in the Message event. Thank you, though. The other library has worked.