# convert array of numbers to written form - e.g. 0 -> "zero"

Tags: javascript, angular

How to accepts an array of numbers and returns an array of numbers in written form e.g.

[0,0,6,2,7] → [“zero”, “zero”, “six”,"two","seven"]

I want to input and return array of values not one value?

```
<div>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="number" placeholder="Input Number"/>
    <div id="word">{{words[number]}}</div>
</div>


{{numbers[number]}}





<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="stringOfNumbers" placeholder="Input Number"/>
{{stringOfNumbers}}
<br>
{{arrayOfNumbers}}




words= ['zero','One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','seven','eight'];

stringOfNumbers = "1,2,3,4";
arrayOfNumbers = this.stringOfNumbers .split(',');
```

Comment: I think youre going to have to write your own functino for this

Comment: How you are creating the numbering array? somewhere in backend?

Comment: Is this constant array or dynamic?

Comment: @QusaySaad, if you only has numbres from 0 to 9 is easy: only arrayString=arrayOfNumber.map(x=>words[+x]) //see that "+" is because your arrayOfNumber are "strings"

Comment: @QusaySaad, I add an answer, please check and try use "Angular", not javaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improve my comment: (the stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jhvfjv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts))

```
//The .html
<input [ngModel]="numbers" (ngModelChange)="calculeNumber($event)">
{{result|json}}

//The .ts
export class AppComponent  {
  numbers:string;
  result:string[]=[];
  words= ['zero','One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','seven','eight'];
  calculeNumber(  numbers:any){
    this.result=numbers.split(',').map(x=>
    {

      return this.words[+x]
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: just use this.result=numbers.split(''). -are two sinple quotes-. If you want a string, not an array of string use join(',') to convert array to string

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a middleware for this (check out this answer: [Convert digits into words with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766951/convert-digits-into-words-with-javascript), it's pretty much hardcoding. Add an event listener every time the input value changes and loop through the array.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].addEventListener('change', function(){
    alert("Input changed!");
    // Code goes here
});
```

Comment: The question is about "angular", please, not use addEventListener