# Numeric to alphabet code is not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Recently I made a function called Converter. It was working perfectly in the morning and now when I am using it, the code is not being able to run when I type numeric like 3 it should print like Three but I do now know what is the problem and problem also not showing. I am new in Javascript
**Here is the code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            function abc()
            {
             //   alert('hello');
                var amt=parseInt(document.getElementById('t1'));
                var d="";
                var ones=Array("","One","Two","Three","four","five");
                var tens=Array("","","Twenty","Thirthy","Fourthy","fifthy");
                var hundreds=Array("","One hundred","Two hundred","Three hundred","Four hundred","Five hundred");
                if(amt>=1&&amt<=19)
                {
                    d=ones[amt];

                }
                  document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML=d;
               // document.write(d);

            }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>

                <input type="text" id="t1" />

                <input type="button"  value="Convert" onclick="abc()" />

                <p id="p1"></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `let amt = document.getElementById('t1').value;` you need the value.

Comment: Usually helpful if you explain what is not working. Are you getting an error in the console? Are you seeing the wrong output or no output displayed in your html?

Comment: Do you not need to get the value of "t1" rather than the element itself? I.e. `document.getElementById("t1").value`

Comment: @benvc one second.

Comment: @benvc no output is being displayed

Comment: @Zakalwe i want to get entered data in textbox and convert it in alphabet numeric

Comment: Thank YouVery Much Guys

Comment: @Learner hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to parse the value of textbox
it should be

> document.getElementById('t1').value

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comment on not grabbing the value.

Use `let amt = document.getElementById('t1').value`. This returns the value inside the input.

Someone made a good example for what you are trying to do here: [Convert digits into words with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766951/convert-digits-into-words-with-javascript)

```js
var a = ['', 'one ', 'two ', 'three ', 'four ', 'five ', 'six ', 'seven ', 'eight ', 'nine ', 'ten ', 'eleven ', 'twelve ', 'thirteen ', 'fourteen ', 'fifteen ', 'sixteen ', 'seventeen ', 'eighteen ', 'nineteen '];
var b = ['', '', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];

function inWords(num) {
  if ((num = num.toString()).length > 9) return 'overflow';
  n = ('000000000' + num).substr(-9).match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{2})$/);
  if (!n) return;
  var str = '';
  str += (n[1] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[1])] || b[n[1][0]] + ' ' + a[n[1][1]]) + 'crore ' : '';
  str += (n[2] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[2])] || b[n[2][0]] + ' ' + a[n[2][1]]) + 'lakh ' : '';
  str += (n[3] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[3])] || b[n[3][0]] + ' ' + a[n[3][1]]) + 'thousand ' : '';
  str += (n[4] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[4])] || b[n[4][0]] + ' ' + a[n[4][1]]) + 'hundred ' : '';
  str += (n[5] != 0) ? ((str != '') ? 'and ' : '') + (a[Number(n[5])] || b[n[5][0]] + ' ' + a[n[5][1]]) + 'only ' : '';
  return str;
}

document.getElementById('number').onkeyup = function() {
  document.getElementById('words').innerHTML = inWords(document.getElementById('number').value);
};
```

```html
<span id="words"></span>
<input id="number" type="text" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Your bug was caused of this line: `parseInt(document.getElementById('t1'));`
You were trying to parseInt(html input element). There is no way to parse HTML value to int, so it was returning NaN, which cannot be converted to "Three" or any other number.
Here's working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            function abc()
            {
              
                var amt=document.getElementById('t1').value;
                var d="";
                var ones=Array("","One","Two","Three","four","five");
                var tens=Array("","","Twenty","Thirthy","Fourthy","fifthy");
                var hundreds=Array("","One hundred","Two hundred","Three hundred","Four hundred","Five hundred");
                if(amt>=1&&amt<=19)
                {
                    d=ones[amt];
                }
                  document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML=d;
               // document.write(d);

            }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>

                <input type="text" id="t1" />

                <input type="button"  value="Convert" onclick="abc()" />

                <p id="p1"></p>

    </body>
</html>
```