# Is there any function in Javascript for converting numbers (with decimal places) to words?

Tags: javascript, function, suitescript2.0

I want to convert a calculated amount to words.

For 2 to 3 decimal places, as the amount is in USD(e.g. 230.54) as well as Omani Riyals(e.g. 230.542).
I tried one function mentioned in Stackoverflow but it doesnt go for 3 decimal places.i.e [Convert digits into words with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766951/convert-digits-into-words-with-javascript)
but the functions either dont work for decimal places or do not include 3 decimal places.

For example if the number is 235.45 than words should be 
`TWO HUNDRED THIRTY FIVE AND 45 CENTS` 
or
 `TWO HUNDRED THIRTY FIVE AND 45/100 DOLLARS`
Same for the Omari Riyals: If amount is 235.456, than 
`TWO HUNDRED THIRTY FIVE AND 456 FILS` 
or
 `TWO HUNDRED THIRTY FIVE AND 450/1000 RIYALS`

i tried this but it outputs only numbers before decimal:

```
function converttoWords(amount) {
    var words = new Array();
    words[0] = '';
    words[1] = 'One';
    words[2] = 'Two';
    words[3] = 'Three';
    words[4] = 'Four';
    words[5] = 'Five';
    words[6] = 'Six';
    words[7] = 'Seven';
    words[8] = 'Eight';
    words[9] = 'Nine';
    words[10] = 'Ten';
    words[11] = 'Eleven';
    words[12] = 'Twelve';
    words[13] = 'Thirteen';
    words[14] = 'Fourteen';
    words[15] = 'Fifteen';
    words[16] = 'Sixteen';
    words[17] = 'Seventeen';
    words[18] = 'Eighteen';
    words[19] = 'Nineteen';
    words[20] = 'Twenty';
    words[30] = 'Thirty';
    words[40] = 'Forty';
    words[50] = 'Fifty';
    words[60] = 'Sixty';
    words[70] = 'Seventy';
    words[80] = 'Eighty';
    words[90] = 'Ninety';
    amount = amount.toString();
    var atemp = amount.split(".");
    var number = atemp[0].split(",").join("");
    var n_length = number.length;
    var words_string = "";
    if (n_length <= 9) {
      var n_array = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
      var received_n_array = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i < n_length; i++) {
        received_n_array[i] = number.substr(i, 1);
      }
      for (var i = 9 - n_length, j = 0; i < 9; i++ , j++) {
        n_array[i] = received_n_array[j];
      }
      for (var i = 0, j = 1; i < 9; i++ , j++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 7) {
          if (n_array[i] == 1) {
            n_array[j] = 10 + parseInt(n_array[j]);
            n_array[i] = 0;
          }
        }
      }
      value = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 7) {
          value = n_array[i] * 10;
        } else {
          value = n_array[i];
        }
        if (value != 0) {
          words_string += words[value] + " ";
        }
        if ((i == 1 && value != 0) || (i == 0 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
          words_string += "Crores ";
        }
        if ((i == 3 && value != 0) || (i == 2 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
          words_string += "Lakhs ";
        }
        if ((i == 5 && value != 0) || (i == 4 && value != 0 && n_array[i + 1] == 0)) {
          words_string += "Thousand ";
        }
        if (i == 6 && value != 0 && (n_array[i + 1] != 0 && n_array[i + 2] != 0)) {
          //words_string += "Hundred and ";
          words_string += "Hundred ";
        } else if (i == 6 && value != 0) {
          words_string += "Hundred ";
        }
      }
      words_string = words_string.split("  ").join(" ");
    }
    return words_string;
}
```

Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: It looks like you just need to truncate to an integer, convert the integer to words, and then convert the fractional part to a fraction or "CENTS" / "FILS" text as appropriate and append. What have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @nico 
i tried developing this(editing my question), but its giving output for only the amount before decimals.

Comment: @curiousKido answer posted for your use and vote

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `N/format/i18n` module. The locale can be set according to the ISO 639-2 code.

Try this in your browser console;

```
var i18n;   
require(['N/format/i18n'],
  function(i8) {
    i18n = i8;
  });               
i18n.spellOut({number: 145.32, locale:'eng'});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Feb 2022 : Generic and Short 'Currency to Words' Javascript Function

#### Handle all Currencies in English

---

I have developed the following short Javascript function that can convert any Currency Number into words including decimal places (fractions).

The function uses US English Grammer for writing numbers into words.

### Syntax

```
currencyToWords(number, currancy, format={})

number    : any numeric or number in string form for large numbers
currency  : object holding the currency information as follows:
            {
             country    : the country Name       (e.g.: 'US')
             majorSingle: Major Unit Single Name (e.g.: 'Dollar')
             majorPlural: Major Unit Plural Name (e.g.: 'Dollars')
             minorSingle: Minor Sub-Unit Single  (e.g.: 'Cent')
             minorPlural: Minor Sub-Unit Plural  (e.g.: 'Cents')
             fraction   : Decimal Places Number  (e.g.: 2)
             };
format    : object holding the format for the minor (sub-units) using
            'minor' parameters, as follows:
            'numeric' : Sub-Units in Numeric Form (i.g. 35 Cents)
            'fraction': Sub-Units in Fractional Form (i.g. 35/100 US Dollar)
            empty or other (default): Sub-Units in Words Form
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Example 1: Convert US Dollars in Default Mode**

```
    let currancy = {
    country    : "US",     // country Name
    majorSingle: "Dollar", // Major Unit Single
    majorPlural: "Dollars",// Major Unit Plural
    minorSingle: "Cent",   // Minor Sub-Unit Single
    minorPlural: "Cents",  // Minor Sub-Unit Plural
    fraction   : 2,        // Decimal Places
    };

console.log(currencyToWords(50,currancy));
// Fifty US Dollars

console.log(currencyToWords(20.23,currancy));
// Twenty US Dollars, and Twenty-Three Cents

console.log(currencyToWords(0.99,currancy));
// Zero US Dollar, and Ninety-Nine Cents

console.log(currencyToWords(100.2,currancy));
// One Hundred US Dollars, and Twenty Cents

console.log(currencyToWords(1.01,currancy));
// One US Dollar, and One Cent

console.log(currencyToWords(0.01,currancy));
// Zero US Dollar, and One Cent

console.log(currencyToWords(520.01,currancy));
// Five Hundred Twenty US Dollars, and One Cent
```

**Example 2: Convert US Dollars with Sub-Units (Minor) in 'numeric' Format**

```
console.log(currencyToWords(50,currancy,{minor:"numeric"}));
// Fifty US Dollars

console.log(currencyToWords(20.23,currancy,{minor:"numeric"}));
// Twenty US Dollars, and 23 Cents

console.log(currencyToWords(0.99,currancy,{minor:"numeric"}));
// Zero US Dollar, and 99 Cents

console.log(currencyToWords(100.2,currancy,{minor:"numeric"}));
// One Hundred US Dollars, and 20 Cents

console.log(currencyToWords(1.01,currancy,{minor:"numeric"}));
// One US Dollar, and 1 Cent

console.log(currencyToWords(0.01,currancy,{minor:"numeric"}));
// Zero US Dollar, and 1 Cent

console.log(currencyToWords(520.01,currancy,{minor:"numeric"}));
// Five Hundred Twenty US Dollars, and 1 Cent
```

**Example 2: Convert US Dollars with Sub-Units (Minor) in 'fraction' Format**

```
console.log(currencyToWords(50,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
// Fifty US Dollars

console.log(currencyToWords(20.23,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
// Twenty, and 23/100 US Dollars

console.log(currencyToWords(0.99,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
// Zero, and 99/100 US Dollar

console.log(currencyToWords(100.2,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
// One Hundred, and 20/100 US Dollars

console.log(currencyToWords(1.01,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
// One, and 1/100 US Dollar

console.log(currencyToWords(0.01,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
// Zero, and 1/100 US Dollar

console.log(currencyToWords(520.01,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
// Five Hundred Twenty, and 1/100 US Dollars
```

### Changing the Currency

You can specify the name of the country, major and minor currency names (singular and plural).
The `fraction` is the number of decimal places for the minor (sub-unit). For US Dollars it is 2 for a Euro: 2, for Kuwait Dinar: 3, or Omani Riyal: 3, etc.

If you want to have a currency without the country name, then set the country name to an empty string ''.

```js
/********************************************************
* @function    : currencyToWords(number, currancy, [format])
* @purpose     : Converts Currency to Words
* @version     : 1.00
* @author      : Mohsen Alyafei
* @licence     : MIT
* @date        : 27 Feb 2022
* @param       : number   [required] numeric or string
*                curr [required] object description
*                format   [optional] with the following parameters:
*                minor: 'numeric' or 'fraction' or none (default)
* @returns     : {string} Currency String in Words
********************************************************/
function currencyToWords(num=0, curr, format={}) {
format=format.minor;
format ??= "";
num=(num+="").split((0.1).toLocaleString().substring(1,2));
let frc = (num[1]+"000").substring(0,curr.fraction), a=", and ",
    cc  = " "+curr.country+(curr.country?" ":"")+(num[0]>1?curr.majorPlural:curr.majorSingle),
    out = numToWords(num[0])+(format=="fraction" && num[1]?"":cc);
if (num[1]) {
    let sub=frc>1?curr.minorPlural:curr.minorSingle;
    if      (format=="numeric")  out+=a+(+frc)+" "+sub;
    else if (format=="fraction") out+=a+(+frc)+"/1"+"0".repeat(curr.fraction)+cc;
    else    out+=a+numToWords(frc)+" "+sub;
}
return out;
//----------------------------------------------------------------
function numToWords(num = 0) {
if (num == 0) return "Zero";
num= ("0".repeat(2*(num+="").length%3)+num).match(/.{3}/g);
let out="",
    T10s=["","One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Eleven","Twelve","Thirteen","Fourteen","Fifteen","Sixteen","Seventeen","Eighteen","Nineteen"],
    T20s=["","","Twenty","Thirty","Forty","Fifty","Sixty","Seventy","Eighty","Ninety"],
    sclT=["","Thousand","Million","Billion","Trillion","Quadrillion"];
return num.forEach((n,i) => {
if (+n) {
 let h=+n[0], t=+n.substring(1), scl=sclT[num.length-i-1];
 out+=(out?" ":"")+(h?T10s[h]+" Hundred":"")+(h && t?" ":"")+(t<20?T10s[t]:T20s[+n[1]]+(+n[2]?"-":"")+T10s[+n[2]]);
 out+=(out && scl?" ":"")+scl;
}}),out;
}
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------










//=========================================
//             Test Code
//=========================================

let currancy = {
country    : "US",     // country Name
majorSingle: "Dollar", // Major Unit Single
majorPlural: "Dollars",// Major Unit Plural
minorSingle: "Cent",   // Minor Sub-Unit Single
minorPlural: "Cents",  // Minor Sub-Unit Plural
fraction   : 2,        // Decimal Places
};

// default. sub-units in word format
console.log(currencyToWords(50,currancy));
console.log(currencyToWords(20.23,currancy));
console.log(currencyToWords(0.99,currancy));
console.log(currencyToWords(100.2,currancy));
console.log(currencyToWords(1.01,currancy));
console.log(currencyToWords(0.01,currancy));
console.log(currencyToWords(520.01,currancy));
console.log("-".repeat(50));

// sub-units in numeric format
console.log(currencyToWords(50,currancy,{minor:"numeric"}));
console.log(currencyToWords(20.23,currancy,{minor:"numeric"}));
console.log(currencyToWords(0.99,currancy,{minor:"numeric"}));
console.log(currencyToWords(100.2,currancy,{minor:"numeric"}));
console.log(currencyToWords(1.01,currancy,{minor:"numeric"}));
console.log(currencyToWords(0.01,currancy,{minor:"numeric"}));
console.log(currencyToWords(520.01,currancy,{minor:"numeric"}));
console.log("-".repeat(50));

// sub-units in fractional format
console.log(currencyToWords(50,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
console.log(currencyToWords(20.23,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
console.log(currencyToWords(0.99,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
console.log(currencyToWords(100.2,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
console.log(currencyToWords(1.01,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
console.log(currencyToWords(0.01,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
console.log(currencyToWords(520.01,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
console.log("-".repeat(50));

currancy = {
    country    : "Omani",  // country Name
    majorSingle: "Riyal", // Major Unit Single
    majorPlural: "Riyals",// Major Unit Plural
    minorSingle: "Baisa",  // Minor Sub-Unit Single
    minorPlural: "Baisa",  // Minor Sub-Unit Plural
    fraction   : 3,        // Decimal Places
    };

console.log(currencyToWords(50,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
console.log(currencyToWords(200.234,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
console.log(currencyToWords(2000.99,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
console.log(currencyToWords(30100.2,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
console.log(currencyToWords(3456.001,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
console.log(currencyToWords(500.01,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
console.log(currencyToWords(22.1,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
console.log(currencyToWords(0.45,currancy,{minor:"fraction"}));
```