# How to get last digit of a number in words (javascript)

Tags: javascript, string

```
function main(englishName) {
var number = englishName;
var lastone = +number.toString().split('').pop();

console.log(lastone);
}
```

This is what I got so far but not sure how to get the digit to switch too a word. Such as two, one, three, etc.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are looking for a digit to word string conversion? So "1" => "one", "2" => "two" ? If so, then your question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766951/convert-digits-into-words-with-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookup object with numbers as keys and words as values

```js
const data = {
  '1': 'one',
  '2': 'two'
}

const num = 132;
const lastNum = num.toString().split('').pop()

console.log(lastNum, 'in word form is', data[lastNum])
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make an object with keys as numbers in words and their corresponding values and then use `split(" ")` and `pop()`, to retrieve the corresponding digit simply pass it to the object

```js
function main(numberinwords) {
const numberobj={"one":1,"two":2,"three":3,"twenty":20,"hundered":100}
var lastone = numberinwords.toString().split(" ").pop();
   return numberobj[lastone]
}

console.log(main("hundred twenty two"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const field = document.querySelector('input');
const paraph = document.querySelector('#numberInWords');

function main(number) {
  // Since you want the last number and it will 
  // always be 0-9 you can create an array with the numbers in words
  let numbers = [
    'Zero',
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three',
    'Four',
    'Five',
    'Six',
    'Seven',
    'Eight',
    'Nine',
  ];
  let lastNumber = number.toString().split('').pop();
  // If no number is entered, numbers[+lastNumber] returns
  // undefined (except for the space character)
  if (numbers[+lastNumber]) {
    return numbers[+lastNumber];
  } else {
    return 'Please enter a number';
  }
}

field.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  paraph.textContent = `Number In Words: ${main(e.target.value)}`;
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
<p id="numberInWords"></p>
```