# convert number to words in Angular

Tags: angular

how can i convert number to word in angular

like: "1232"  to "one thousand  two hundred thirty two"

I am new in angular can any one help me to solve this?

Comment: There is no Angular way to do so. Rather you want to try something like [number-to-words](https://www.npmjs.com/package/number-to-words).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the algorithm posted by @thank-you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766951/convert-digits-into-words-with-javascript#answer-30524915) and convert this into a pipe.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3y9psb)

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
   name: 'numberToWords'
})
export class NumberToWordsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): string {
    if (value && isInteger(value))
      return  numToWords(value);
    
    return value;
  }
}

const isInteger = function(x: any) {
   return x % 1 === 0;
}


const arr = x => Array.from(x);
const num = x => Number(x) || 0;
const str = x => String(x);
const isEmpty = xs => xs.length === 0;
const take = n => xs => xs.slice(0,n);
const drop = n => xs => xs.slice(n);
const reverse = xs => xs.slice(0).reverse();
const comp = f => g => x => f (g (x));
const not = x => !x;
const chunk = n => xs =>
  isEmpty(xs) ? [] : [take(n)(xs), ...chunk (n) (drop (n) (xs))];
// numToWords :: (Number a, String a) => a -> String
let numToWords = n => {
  let a = [
    '', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four',
    'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine',
    'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen',
    'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'
  ];
  let b = [
    '', '', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty',
    'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'
  ];
  let g = [
    '', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion', 'quadrillion',
    'quintillion', 'sextillion', 'septillion', 'octillion', 'nonillion'
  ];
  // this part is really nasty still
  // it might edit this again later to show how Monoids could fix this up
  let makeGroup = ([ones,tens,huns]) => {
    return [
      num(huns) === 0 ? '' : a[huns] + ' hundred ',
      num(ones) === 0 ? b[tens] : b[tens] && b[tens] + '-' || '',
      a[tens+ones] || a[ones]
    ].join('');
  };
  // "thousands" constructor; no real good names for this, i guess
  let thousand = (group,i) => group === '' ? group : `${group} ${g[i]}`;
  // execute !
  if (typeof n === 'number') return numToWords(String(n));
  if (n === '0')             return 'zero';
  return comp (chunk(3)) (reverse) (arr(n))
    .map(makeGroup)
    .map(thousand)
    .filter(comp(not)(isEmpty))
    .reverse()
    .join(' ');
};
```

Comment: thank you soooooo.......... much @pixelbits :)

Answer (score 2):

An simple module to convert numbers to words for South Asian numbering system

Install

```
npm i num-words
```

Usage

```
const numWords = require('num-words')
 
const amountInWords = numWords(12345) // twelve thousand three hundred and forty five
```

Refer : https://www.npmjs.com/package/num-words

Or

Use this logic

```
var a = ['','one ','two ','three ','four ', 'five ','six ','seven ','eight ','nine ','ten ','eleven ','twelve ','thirteen ','fourteen ','fifteen ','sixteen ','seventeen ','eighteen ','nineteen '];
var b = ['', '', 'twenty','thirty','forty','fifty', 'sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety'];

function inWords (num) {
    if ((num = num.toString()).length > 9) return 'overflow';
    n = ('000000000' + num).substr(-9).match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{2})$/);
    if (!n) return; var str = '';
    str += (n[1] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[1])] || b[n[1][0]] + ' ' + a[n[1][1]]) + 'crore ' : '';
    str += (n[2] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[2])] || b[n[2][0]] + ' ' + a[n[2][1]]) + 'lakh ' : '';
    str += (n[3] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[3])] || b[n[3][0]] + ' ' + a[n[3][1]]) + 'thousand ' : '';
    str += (n[4] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[4])] || b[n[4][0]] + ' ' + a[n[4][1]]) + 'hundred ' : '';
    str += (n[5] != 0) ? ((str != '') ? 'and ' : '') + (a[Number(n[5])] || b[n[5][0]] + ' ' + a[n[5][1]]) + 'only ' : '';
    return str;
}

document.getElementById('number').onkeyup = function () {
    document.getElementById('words').innerHTML = inWords(document.getElementById('number').value);
};
```

HTML:

```
<span id="words"></span>
<input id="number" type="text" />
```