# Convert digits into words with JavaScript in PDF Form

Tags: javascript, pdf-form

When I use the code as mentioned by Salman in [Convert digits into words with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766951/convert-digits-into-words-with-javascript/14767071#14767071) in my PDF form in Foxit Reader - custom calculation script, it does not work and when I see the console it says :

```
======== Field : calculate ========
[ Line: 00015 { ReferenceError } ] : document is not defined
```

What I need to modify in this to get it working in PDF form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously need to change the code

```
document.getElementById('number').onkeyup = function () {
    document.getElementById('words').innerHTML = inWords(document.getElementById('number').value);
};
```

to the equivalent in foxit

Something like

```
this.getField ("words").value = inWords(this.getField("number").value)
```

https://www.foxitsoftware.com/blog/how-to-create-forms-that-perform-simple-mathematical-calculations/

https://developers.foxitsoftware.com/kb/article/javascript-pdf-sdk-java/

https://www.foxitsoftware.com/blog/how-to-add-javascript-functionality-to-pdf-forms-without-coding/

Comment: Great. I have not used foxit so I had to investigate without being able to test my hypothesis.