# I want to format numbers using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to format numbers using JavaScript.

```
For example:
input n < 1000
n=1 => one
n=2 => two 
n=3 => three
```

Comment: Does this answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14767071/11260991

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer it without a Libary, you can do something like:

```
var num = "zero one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen".split(" ");
var tens = "twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety".split(" ");

function number2words(n){
    if (n < 20) return num[n];
    var digit = n%10;
    if (n < 100) return tens[~~(n/10)-2] + (digit? "-" + num[digit]: "");
    if (n < 1000) return num[~~(n/100)] +" hundred" + (n%100 == 0? "": " and " + number2words(n%100));
    return number2words(~~(n/1000)) + " thousand" + (n%1000 != 0? " " + number2words(n%1000): "");
}

console.log(number2words(12))
```

(found here: [Transform numbers to words in lakh / crore system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766951/transform-numbers-to-words-in-lakh-crore-system))

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library to do that called [number-to-words](https://www.npmjs.com/package/number-to-words)

```
import { toWords } from 'number-to-words';


console.log(toWords(13)); // => “thirteen”
 
// Decimal numbers:
console.log(toWords(1.2))
// Integer Numbers:
console.log(toWords(1))// => “one”
```

Live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-4rj4iw?file=index.js

Comment: Please reconsider answering low-effort questions?